# Video tracking in Google Tag Manager not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, youtube, google-tag-manager, video-tracking

I used [this guide](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-video-tracking/) to implement youtube and vimeo tracking on a site but it's not working. Initially vimeo worked, but now it has stopped.

Is it something to do with the way GTM is added to the site (is code better than using the GTM plugin? FYI I use the code).

I've tried so many solves after pouring through Google and nothing seems to work. Happy to share code/screenshots if needed.

Comment: well, just trying things is not extremely helpful without proper debugging. Did you see how that article asks you to deploy a listener for vimeo messages? In that listener, they use onMessageReceived function as a callback. Make sure that first, the window listener works as intended and put something in the callback to make sure it fires on vimeo events. Note that for this debugging, you don't need GTM at all. It's all before GTM. Once you make sure the listener and the callback work, only then should you go debug GTM.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.